# Python - Selenium send_keys() não funciona neste campo do formulário

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Fiz a identificação correta com xPath, o software .clear() funciona perfeitamente, contudo o send_keys não funciona de forma alguma. Segue o código HTML do formulário:

```
<input id="yui-gen19" name="e_dt_ini_0" size="12" value="01/06/2015" class="dw-params43C55" 
tabindex="1" style="position: absolute; left: 3.49in; top: 0in; width: 0.967in; height: 0.197in;" 
onfocus="{dw_params.itemGainFocus(0,10,this,dw_params.gobs.e_dt_ini); dw_params.selectControlContent(this);}" 
onclick="{var ret;  ret= dw_params.itemClicked(0,10,'e_dt_ini',0,-1); return ret;}" 
onchange="{this.bChanged = true;}" onkeypress="return DW_EditKeyPressed(event, this, -1);" 
onblur="{dw_params.itemLoseFocus (this);}" type="text">
```

Tudo mais funciona perfeitamente. Esse campo do formulário é insuportável até para o preenchimento direto pelo usuário.

O código em Python:

```
 # Preenche o Formulário
    hoje = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%d/%m/%Y')
    dataInicioXpath = "//*[@id='dw_params_detail_0']/input[4]"
    dataFimXpath = "//*[@id='dw_params_detail_0']/input[3]"
    medicoXpath ="//*[@id='dw_params_detail_4']/input[3]"
    relButtonXpath = "//*[@id='bt_emitir']"


    dataInicioElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name("e_dt_ini_0")) # find_element_by_xpath(dataInicioXpath))
    dataFimElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(dataFimXpath))
    medicoElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(medicoXpath))
    relButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(relButtonXpath))


    dataInicioElement.click()
    dataInicioElement.clear()
    dataInicioElement.send_keys(hoje)
    dataFimElement.click()
    dataFimElement.clear()
    dataFimElement.send_keys(hoje)
    medicoElement.clear()
    medicoElement.send_keys("11111")
    relButtonElement.click()
```

Comment: Mostra a identificação com o xPath

Comment: Ah, seria legal você dizer pra gente se ele está dentro de um `<iframe>`.

Comment: `Esse campo do formulário é insuportável até para o preenchimento direto pelo usuário.` eu consegui preencher na mão

Answer (score 1):

Você já tentou passar esse valor via javascript?

```
webdriver.execute_script("document.getElementById('yui-gen19').value = '"+hoje+"'")
```

Comment: Deu esse erro: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: document.getElementById(...) is null

Answer (score 0):

Por que não seleciona diretamente pelo `id`?

```
campo = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#yui-gen19')
```

Comment: Tentei já de várias formas. A identificação do campo funciona bem em todas elas. O que não funciona é o key_send. O campo é chato até de ser preenchido manualmente. Você vai digitando os números do dia e ele salta sozinho o mês.

Comment: Já experimentou colocar um `time.sleep(0.5)` para cada caracter digitado?

Comment: Tentei preencher com apenas 1 caractere e ele não aceitou. Vou tentar com o time.sleep. Obrigado =)

Comment: Também não funcionou.